# How to set priority of action in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, action

For example, I have a button, when click this button, it call an action: doAction1.
And an View: when touch in it, it call an action doAction2.

When clicked in this button, I touched in view, too.
Is it have any property to set priority to call doAction1 or doAction2?

Comment: yes, you can set priority to actions. I would recommend using [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and NSOperationQueue to manage background activity that you need to be able to cancel arbitrarily and set priority. See [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you you put a Tapgesturerecogniyer to container view.You can ignore the tap gesture if user has tapped on the button.Just overwrite the fooling method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
// test if touched view is unbutton

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {

        return NO; // ignore the touch
    }

return YES;
```

}